# Why does Google not support valid URLs with &amp; in query string?

Tags: url, url-encoding, google-maps-static-api

Trying to validate the following HTML with the W3C validator will throw 3 errors (as of 2013-10-30):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title>asdf</title></head>
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&size=279x183&markers=50.916780,5.347420&sensor=false" alt="map">
```

The 3 errors are all the same:

> & did not start a character reference. (& probably should have been escaped as &.)

Unfortunately, conforming to the W3C here will lead to the static maps image not being rendered. Try to embed an `img` tag with the following URL as the value for its `src` attribute:

```
<img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&amp;size=279x183&amp;markers=50.916780,5.347420&amp;sensor=false">
```

This returns an error by Google stating:

> The Google Maps API server rejected your request. Invalid request. Missing the 'size' parameter.

Why does the Google Static Maps API not support valid URLs with `&amp;` in query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You escaped the `&` characters correctly.

Note that you can’t enter the URI with escaped ampersands directly into the address bar of your browser. It only works if used in HTML (i.e. in `href` and `src` attributes).

The [URL in question works](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?zoom=13&size=279x183&markers=50.916780,5.347420&sensor=false) perfectly as link (and also as image).

---

Note that you probably [don’t *have* to escape](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/ambiguous-ampersands) these ampersands (as they seem to be unambiguous); but to be always on the safe side, simply escape them all.

Comment: Looks like Google now supports the escaped `&` characters in the `img` src attribute.