# Should an ampersand be URL encoded in a query string?

Tags: url, url-encoding, ampersand

For example I quite often see this URL come up.

```
https://ghbtns.com/github-btn.html?user=example&repo=card&type=watch&count=true
```

Is the `&` meant to be `&amp;` or should/can it be left as `&`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Do I encode ampersands in <a href...>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705591/do-i-encode-ampersands-in-a-href)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [**rfc3986**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986):

> ***Reserved Characters***
> URIs include components and subcomponents that are delimited by characters in the "reserved" set. These characters are called "**reserved**" because they may (or may not) be defined as delimiters by the generic syntax, by each scheme-specific syntax, or by the implementation-specific syntax of a URI's dereferencing algorithm.
> ...

```
  reserved    = gen-delims / sub-delims

  gen-delims  = ":" / "/" / "?" / "#" / "[" / "]" / "@"

  sub-delims  = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
              / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

> The purpose of **reserved characters** is to provide a set of delimiting
> characters that are distinguishable from other data within a URI. URIs
> that differ in the replacement of a reserved character with its
> corresponding percent-encoded octet are not equivalent.
> Percent-encoding a reserved character, or decoding a percent-encoded
> octet that corresponds to a reserved character, will change how the
> URI is interpreted by most applications.
> ...
> URI producing applications should percent-encode data octets that
> correspond to characters in the reserved set unless these characters
> are specifically allowed by the URI scheme to represent data in that
> component.  If a reserved character is found in a URI component and
> **no delimiting role** is known for that character, then it must be
> interpreted as representing the data octet corresponding to that
> character's encoding in US-ASCII.

So `&` within a URL should be encoded if it's part of the value and has *no delimiting role*.
Here's simple PHP code fragment using `urlencode()` function:

```
<?php
    $query_string = 'foo=' . urlencode($foo) . '&bar=' . urlencode($bar);
    echo '<a href="mycgi?' . htmlentities($query_string) . '">';
?>
```

Comment: Your answer does not cover rfc1866 aspects. The meaning of "delimiting" character here is not visible in your code example. The quote you show basically tells when to escape reserved characters. Example: `/?user=tester&password=123&456` the first `&` is a delimiting character, the second `&` is not. Correct would be: `/?user=tester&password=123%26456`. `htmlentities()` is something from rfc1866 "3.2.1. Data Characters": `&` is a data character (to introduce an entity). Correct in HTML would be: `/?user=tester&amp;password=123%26456`. html entities must be encoded in ALL HTML attribute values.

Answer (score 6):

`&amp;` is for encoding the ampersand **in HTML**.

For example, in a hyperlink:

```html
<a href="/github-btn.html?user=example&amp;repo=card&amp;type=watch&amp;count=true">…</a>
```

(Note that this [only changes the link, not the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19738552/1591669). The URL is still `/github-btn.html?user=example&repo=card&type=watch&count=true`.)

While you may encode every `&` (that is part of the content) with `&amp;` in HTML, you are only required to encode [ambiguous ampersands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20586767/1591669).