# how to get complete value in a variable in the page url php

Tags: php, url, get

I have this URL in my page

> https://www.albaama.com/search.php?qry=Fashion%20&%20Clothing

and I use this code below to echo out the value of the variable **'qry'**

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['qry'])) {
        echo $_GET['qry'];
    } 
    else {
        echo "";
    } 
?>
```

but whenever I echo it, I only get **Fashion** instead of **Fashion & Clothing**.
please how do I get the complete value?

Comment: `&` should be encoded too.

Comment: @u_mulder i don't understand

Comment: Not sure if it's a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907682/should-an-ampersand-be-url-encoded-in-a-query-string, but it covers the principle the & should be encoded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query string: `https://www.albaama.com/search.php?qry=Fashion%20&%20Clothing`

Translates to this:

- URL: https://www.albaama.com/search.php
- Parameter 1: qry="Fashion " ("Fashion" and a trailing space)
- Parameter 2: " Clothing" ("Clothing" and a leading space)

The problem is that `&` introduces a *second* parameter.

You need to [urlencode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php) the entire string "Fashion & Clothing"