# How can I consider special character(&) as value in one of the query parameter

Tags: node.js, split, special-characters, query-string

In GET API I have value as,

**title=my&title**

where the value from query param title returns only **my** and splits from **&** character.

Can anyone help me with how can I include & in my value?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should an ampersand be URL encoded in a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907682/should-an-ampersand-be-url-encoded-in-a-query-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query parameters should be [URL-encoded](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP) in order to differenciate a separating `&` from a random character.

The solution is to encode the value before sending it through the request. You can do so by passing your value to `encodeURIComponent()`. You can then parse it the same way and decode it using `decodeURIComponent()`, e. g. :

```js
encodeURIComponent('my&title') -> 'my%26title'
decodeURIComponent('my%26title') -> 'my&title'
```