# How to avoid/stop Angular Meta url sanitizer

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm using Angular build in Meta tag setter for my open graph tags.

The code is rendered server-side with Angular Universal

```
import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
...
export class MetaTagsService {
  constructor(
    private metaTagSetter: Meta,
   ...
)

this.metaTagSetter.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', url:`${page.ogData.imgUrl}` });
```

but when pass something like this for page.ogData.imgUrl:

```
https://somedomain.com?param=123&param2=345
```

it ends like that in the output

```
https://somedomain.com?param=123&amp;param2=345
```

In other words, the sanitizer edit the &

How can avoid that behavior?

Comment: Isn’t that the expected behavior? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/41907682

Comment: Perhaps it is, but I need to server the link as it is, without sanitize