# Named entity expected, got none

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress, elementor

Please check the below code

```
<!-- Calendly inline widget begin -->
<div class="calendly-inline-widget" data-url="https://calendly.com/example/chat?text_color=202a3b&primary_color=4eaf4e" style="min-width:800px;height:800px;"></div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://assets.calendly.com/assets/external/widget.js"></script>
<!-- Calendly inline widget end -->
```

I am trying to add this code as an HTML block in my WordPress website powered by `Elementor Pro`. I am getting the error `name entity expected, got none` for the `div` section.

What is causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character `&` starts an [entity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity).

`&primary_color` isn't a valid entity, hence the error.

The `&` should be represented by the entity for `&` which is `&amp;`.

Comment: Thank you. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is incorrect in this context. This is an Elementor error, not a real issue. Since the ampersand is part of the URL as a delimiter, it's valid and is NOT an entity. (Indeed it should NOT be encoded, which would change it from a delimiter to a value.)

[Should an ampersand be URL encoded in a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41907682/should-an-ampersand-be-url-encoded-in-a-query-string)

So, an ampersand within a URL should be encoded ONLY if it's part of a value and has no delimiting role (separating values).

Elementor needs to fix this, not you. Vendors who give us embed code formatted this way are correct, not Elementor.